# FFMPEG does not convert a specific file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this file that comes from of an unknown brand, however when I use the code that I am used to normally use in other models it does not work, appears format dav detected only with low score of 1 misdetection possible. I use the following code:

```
forfiles /s /M *.dav /C "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @file -vf setpts = 2.0 * PTS @ fname.avi -n"
```

video download link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fwQMA8gYu8pLwW5JJ2_MccWx7U3FDC3f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java], [tag:javascript] or [tag:c]? I doubt many people are going to download random files from Google Drive. You should post a complete ffmpeg command line and strip out all the batch stuff. Show the complete output of the command you run and potentially the output of `ffprobe -i yourFile.ext`.

Comment: I WAS NOT GETTING TO POST THE QUESTION. THE SITE REQUIRES THAT I PLACE 5 TAGS, WHEN THE FFMPEG ONLY IS WHAT MATTERS, I AM EXCUSING. I HAVE A .BAT FILE THAT RUNS THIS CODE LINE EVERY DAY 8 HOURS AT NIGHT.
THIS .DAV VIDEO FILE CAME FROM AN APPLIANCE DIFFERENT THAN I WAS USED AND IT WAS THE FIRST TIME THE CODE HAS NOT BEEN CONVERTED TO AVI.

Comment: I am working at a car inspection station in Brazil, and the inspection process is filmed. I USE THIS CODE LINE TO CONVERT VIDEOS FROM .DAV FORMAT TO AVI AND SO DISCUP SPACE ON DISK. HOWEVER THIS NEW DEVICE SAVES IN A DAV FILE I CAN'T CONVERT WITH FFMPEG .. I HAVE TRIED TO UPDATE THE VERSION .. BUT IT WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide the details I asked for in my first comment. YOU DO NOT NEED TO USE ALL CAPS.

Comment: OK . forgive me . I'm new here and didn't know how to proceed.
Can you take my doubt?

Answer (score 0):

With this file you have to tell `ffmpeg` to use the raw H.264 video demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i input.dav -c copy output.mp4
```

Or rename `2020_12_04_09_04_03.dav` to `2020_12_04_09_04_03.h264` before giving it to `ffmpeg`.